# Conditionally setting the template in Magento

Tags: php, magento, overriding

I would like to make a portion of a page available for getting via AJAX. I have in mind to use a URL parameter, `bare`, that would tell Magento to present a page with a different template applied to the *root* block. The *bare* template looks like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content'); ?>
```

That's it! The idea is that a JavaScript method could grab just the `content` of another page and insert it into the DOM where appropriate. (I don't want this to be possible with just any page – only pages that have been marked to do so in layout xml.)

I've read elsewhere that [I should avoid conditional layout xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331684/using-conditions-in-magento-layout-xml). The only other approach I can think of is to override the Page/Html block itself, creating a modified `setTemplate` method, like below. Instinctively, I'm concerned about overriding such a core part of Magento.

```
public function setTemplate($template, $bareTemplate='')
{
    $bareMode = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('bare');
    $targetTemplate = (!empty($bareTemplate) && $bareMode === '1') ? $bareTemplate : $template;
    return parent::setTemplate($targetTemplate);
}
```

What better approaches haven't I thought of?

Comment: It would help to understand the purpose and see examples of the desired results if we're to offer "better approaches" :) Otherwise, any advice is likely to be a bit generic, yes? What is the desired goal? Do you really want a page to look like it belongs to a different theme? Or are you trying to get some customized layout rendered for a specific product/category/sale?

Comment: @Kato so edited by adding an example of the *bare* template and what it's to be used for.

Comment: Have you considered just fetching the page via HTTP and extracting the useful section? If it's just the bare html code you want, this should be a fine/simple answer and save you lots of trouble creating additional templates or changing core.

Comment: "I don't want this to be possible with just any page – only pages that have been marked to do so in layout xml."  I don't really understand this comment either; why would you care if someone adds "bare" to the URL and fetches a page using the custom/alternate template?

Comment: @Kato Fetching an entire page to extract only parts of the code increases the load on the server (it has to construct and render an entire page, instead of just part). As to your second comment, I don't really care that much, but wanted to be clear that my goal is focused on a few specific pages, not the entire site.

Comment: I'm not in your unique circumstance and don't presume to understand it, these are simply questions to consider (as you've asked for approaches you haven't thought of). That said, I just can't imagine that rendering the content of a page in one template vs another is even measurable next to the cost of loading all the core libs and querying the database, even if one page is twice as long. Could caching template parsing in Magento and compressing output before sending to the browser be a much more elegant answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to getting what you want is removing **root** as an output block, replacing it with **content**. Output blocks are just entry points for renderLayout();

To do this in Magento without include-path-hacking `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`, observe the `controller_action_layout_render_before_$this->getFullActionName()` scoped events which are fired in the base action controller class (ref `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::renderLayout()` method).

First configure your model class group and frontend event observer. You'll need to determine the full action name of any route that needs this logic. See `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::renderLayout()`. Example config below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <your_classgroup>
                <class>Your_Classgroup_Model</class>
            </your_classgroup>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_render_before_FULL_ACTION_NAME...>
                <observers>
                    <your_observer_config>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>your_classgroup/observer</class>
                        <method>makeContentBlockTheOutputBlock</method>
                    </your_observer_config>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_render_before_FULL_ACTION_NAME...>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

The event observer logic is easy. Do this:

```
public function makeContentBlockTheOutputBlock($observer)
{
   //Edit: action not passed in to this event; passed in generic generate_blocks event
   if( Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('bare') )
   {
        Mage::app()->getLayout()->removeOutputBlock('root')->addOutputBlock('content');
   }
}
```

HTH.